# No stairs to lower bomb spot?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

It seems that in Couter Strike:Global Offensive on de_nuke there are no stairs in the outside area (head right from terrorist base) to the lower bomb spot. This was the case in CS 1.6 and seems to be the case in VODs from tournaments. I assume it just is not there and another version is played in tournaments, right? Or is there a button or trick to open/reveal the stairs?

Comment: What map is this question about?

Comment: Sorry, I had de_nuke in the title, then deleted and forgot to add somewhere else.

Comment: de_nuke, most likely. It could also be de_aztec but that's not played in tournaments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version used by most tournaments is de_nuke_ve, which was remade by professional player Volcano. You can read more about the changes he made [here](http://volcanotv.tumblr.com/post/28514126215/competitive-version-of-nuke-for-cs-go-released). The main (relevant) difference is that he moved the stairs down to lower to a more accessible area outside. Note that this is unlike any previous version of de_nuke.

Valve's rationale behind the removal of this pathway was that the stairs were very underutilized anyway and that this thus streamlines the action, and while that was true removing it makes the terrorist options incredibly limited and allows the CT's to consolidate even more easily.

As of the patch on December 12, Valve has integrated most of the key aspects of de_nuke_ve into the standard version of de_nuke used by matchmaking.

Comment: Hm, ok, so there really are no stairs in the CS:GO version. I like the streamlining of the maps (the smaller demolition maps are more action, less camping/sneaking long periods) but on de_nuke I really dislike the change. The de_nuke_ve would have been a better choice for CS:GO competitive mode matches.

Comment: @Konsta There has been a large debate in the community about Valve's refusal to put the more competitive versions of maps (generally _se maps) into matchmaking. It cheapens the potential of the system and forces people to pay for things like ESEA, which is pretty annoying.